# bundle execを省略したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

#### 実現したいこと

`bundle exec`を省略したい

#### 発生している問題

`--binstubs=vendor/bin`が非推奨になっているので、
今後推奨される`bundle binstubs --path=vendor/bin`のコマンドを打つとエラーメッセージが表示される

#### 表示されるエラー

```
`bundle binstubs` needs at least one gem to run.
```

#### 使っているツールのバージョン等

Mac OS M1
VScode
ruby 3.1.0
rails "~> 7.0.2", ">= 7.0.2.2"

#### rails new . に至るまでのコマンドの流れ

1. プロジェクトファイルを作成する
   `mkdir sample`
2. ファイル内でbundleを初期化
   `bundle init`
3. Gemfileを編集する
4. gemのインストール先をローカルに設定
   `bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'`
5. bundle execを省略する設定
   `bundle binstubs --path=vendor/bin`
6. gemをインストール
   `bundle install`
7. 新規Railsアプリケーションの作成
   `rails new . -d postgresql`

#### 下記の設定もしています

rails 環境構築部の`bundle exec`を省略する設定を有効にするために`.rbenv`に設定を加える必要がある

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.rbenv/plugins
$ cd ~/.rbenv/plugins
$ git clone https://github.com/ianheggie/rbenv-binstubs.git
```

#### さいごに

`bundle exec`をつければこのまま開発は続けられるが、
`rails g`コマンド等でも毎度`bundle exec`を打つのは非効率なので、できれば解決したいです。
何かわかる方教えてくださると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle binstubs`は実行可能なファイルを「引数で与えられたgemに対して」生成するコマンドです。
https://bundler.io/man/bundle-binstubs.1.html
もし全てのgemに対してbinstubsを生成したい場合は、`--all`オプションを付ける必要があります。

基本的には、`bundle install`コマンドを先に実行しておくとよいでしょう。そうすれば、Bundlerはインストールされたgemに対して処理を行うことができます。

Answer (score 0):

`bundle exec` の文字数が多いのが問題なのであれば、`alias be='bundle exec'` などと alias を貼るのはよく見ます。プロジェクトごとに設定を確認するのが面倒なので、個人的には毎回 `bundle exec` が意識できる書き方にする方を好んでいます。